# Sql server connection errors in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-timeout

I am getting these database errors in my asp.net website

[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).] |
| Query timeout expired |
Login timeout expired |
SQL Server does not exist or access denied

same errors are repeating twice in a week.I get more than 50 errors at a time.

I have checked the errors logs and I ran the queries causing these error there no problem with execution time of these queries.

I asked the sys admin and database admin if there errors in connection there seems to be no problem with the connections as well.

Same data or queries are running the another website on same database but I found no errors on that another  website.

Any insights on what is causing these errors and how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: check if the server running the website had any connectivity issue related to a temporary network unavailability, a driver update, a windowsupdate package install... in the event log you may find some information.

Comment: Thanks Paolo the time out errors rectified after patching the pending updates on servers.but users  getting an 500 error on the websites of this server just for some time 5 mins or so and it just goes off and no errors logs in application or event log and  I am not able to check the error on production browser since this error just goes.  Any insight from will be a great help for me. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3541659/paolo